# Make Jenkins Dashboard Private

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I just installed Jenkins CI on a server and its dashboard is open to the whole world! How do I configure it so that this dashboard can only be viewed by registered users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tick the "Enable Security" checkbox on the main configuration page (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System) and configure what to authenticate against etc.